# Golang icmp ping

Tags: golang, ping, ethernet, icmp

В общем, мне нужно сделать ICMP опрос коммутаторов с помощью яп golang, всё вроде сделано, работает. Одна загвоздка, объектов для опроса тысячи, и чтобы их все опросить и занести в базу данных жив ли коммутатор или нет - понадобится большое количество времени. Проблема была решена, использование горутин, появилась вторая проблема - неэффективность программы. Создавалось количество горутин равное количеству объектов, что сильно нагружает процессор. Что можно вообще сделать? Есть идея отправлять ICMP-пакет на сервер и не ждать от него ответа, идя отправлять пакеты дальше по другим объектам. И сделать обработчик события приходящего пакета, и там уже написать логику, но как такое можно сделать? Асинхронность пытался использовать, всё приводило в итоге к горутинам, и всё той же большой нагрузке.

Comment: а вы сколько пакетов отправляете?

Comment: 4 пакета, и если хотя бы один прошел - считаем что коммутатор в онлайне

Comment: а что 1 пакета не достаточно? а нагрузка большая, если по 1 пакету отправлять?

Comment: На 1 пакет ответа может не последовать, в следствии чего могут быть ложные сбои

Comment: но если нет ответа в 25% случаев, то что-то не так с сервером. разве не говорит это о недоступности сервера?

Comment: Были случаи ложных сбоев, хотя таковых не было. Сервер отвечал на 3 пакета из 4

Comment: а вы профилировавли программу, чтобы узнать что именно нагружает процессор? может что-нибудь можно оптимизировать

Comment: Профилировал, нагружает программу достаточно большое кол-во потоков. Опять же, если делать всё в одном - долго, но и не затратно. А если в большом количестве - сильная нагрузка. У меня на пк все 8 ядер долбились под сотку, что не есть хорошо

Comment: попробуйте [fping](https://techrapiduk.blogspot.com/2017/04/fast-ping-alternative-on-linux.html). или hping3. `hping3 -c 1 -V -p 80 -s 5050 -A 8.8.8.8`.  а вы пробовали заменить ICMP на что-то другое? например достуупность по shh через nc?

Comment: Попробую вариант выше. Нет, пока не рассматриваю доступность через nc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно распараллелить кластерно.

Пусть Q - количество устройств, которое нужно опросить. Создаем горутины, количество которых равно количеству потоков H, а каждой горутине отдать Q/H ip-адресов.

Так теоретически возможно увеличить производительность относительно последовательной отправки пакетов и снизить нагрузку.